# How to use jq to extract joined rows of data from a json doc

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have a JSON doc that looks like:

```
{
"Images": [
    {
        "ImageId": "ami-111",
        "Name": "etl-db",
        "State": "available",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sda",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-AAA",
                    "VolumeSize": "size-AAA"
                }
            },
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sdb",
                "Ebs": {
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-BBB",
                    "VolumeSize": "size-BBB"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I used the follwoing jq command trto get output like:
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-AAA|size-AAA
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-BBB|size-BBB

```
cat json.doc | jq -r '.Images[]|"\(.ImageId)|\(.Name)|\(.State)|\(.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.SnapshotId)|\(.BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeSize)"'
```

However it generates a Cartesian Product for  SnapshotId x VolumeSize

```
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-AAA|size-AAA
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-BBB|size-AAA
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-AAA|size-BBB
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-BBB|size-BBB
```

How can I get the following output?

```
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-AAA|size-AAA
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-BBB|size-BBB
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the unwanted Cartesian product, ensure there is only one call to `.BlockDeviceMappings[]`.

The following filter extracts the information you want as a stream of arrays:

```
   .Images[] | [.ImageId,.Name,.State] + (.BlockDeviceMappings[] | [.Ebs[] ])
```

(In the above, [.Ebs[]] produces an array of the values of `.Ebs`, which may or may not be exactly what you want.)

To convert these arrays into strings with pipe-delimited values, you could pipe the above into `join("|")` or `@tsv | gsub("\t";"|")` to produce (using jq -r):

```
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-AAA|size-AAA
ami-111|etl-db|available|snap-BBB|size-BBB
```